# ¿Como puedo reproducir un TextToSpeech de Android por el altavoz principal (en el que escuchas las llamadas) del dispositivo?

Tags: java, android

Ejecuto el siguiente código pero se reproduce por el altavoz stereo del dispositivo:

```
private TextToSpeech textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this,this);

textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("spa","ESP"));
speak("Hola mundo" );

private void speak(String str){
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

    textToSpeech.speak(str,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null);
    textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(0.0f);
    textToSpeech.setPitch(0.0f);
}
```

Quiero hacer algo parecido a lo que pasa cuando intentas reproducir un sonido en WhatsApp y te lo acercas a la oreja, suena por el altavoz de llamada del dispositivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final pude lograrlo. En primer lugar había que darle los permisos necesarios:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Y luego el código era el siguiente:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);

    textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(1.0f);
    textToSpeech.setPitch(1.0f);
    textToSpeech.speak(str,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

Para poder invocar el método `setSpeakerphoneOn` debes tener los permisos necesarios en tu manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Esto tiene el problema que estas modificando la configuración de audio y se quedara así, salvo que la restablezcas a su valor anterior cuando termines el playback.

> Quiero hacer algo parecido a lo que pasa cuando intentas reproducir un sonido en WhatsApp y te lo acercas a la oreja, suena por el altavoz de llamada del dispositivo.

#### Por otro lado...

...para lo que intentas hacer android tiene un mecanismo que te garantiza (o notifica que no es posible) que el audio será reproducido por el altavoz (o los auriculares). Esto se hace usando el método [`AudioManager.requestAudioFocus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#requestAudioFocus(android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener,%20int,%20int)) con el cual puedes capturar alguno de los streams de audio y reproducir sobre el.

```
// Solicita el foco de audio para realizar una reproducción.
int result = am.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener,
                             // usamos el stream para música (hay otros)
                             AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,
                             // ver documentacion
                            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);

if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
    // preparas la reproducción. 
    textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(1.0f); // << esto es 1.0f
    textToSpeech.setPitch(1.0f);      // << 1.0f tambien

    // le indicas que use el stream de ALARM 
    textToSpeech.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
         .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
         .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
         .build());

    // reproduces el text to speech.
    textToSpeech.speak(str,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);


    // al terminar
    am.abandonAudioFocus(...);
}
```

Ver mas detalles [aquí](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html#RequestFocus) (en inglés)

Comment: Alguna razon para el -1?

Comment: random downvote... ?

Comment: Hola rnd, en primer lugar muchas gracias por responder a la pregunta. Pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema, cuando intento ejecutar el textToSpeech suena por el altavoz no por el auricular de llamada. Si le doy permiso en el manifest para ejecutar el setSpeakerphoneOn(true) no suena por ningún sitio.

Comment: @Antoniodelos solo tengo acceso a un tablet y no tiene "auricular de llamada", pero viendo la doc, probablemente tendrias que usar el stream STREAM_VOICE_CALL, ahora, textToSpeech **no** tiene un USE_VOICE_CALL, y no podrá reproducir directamente sobre ese stream, tendrías que sintetizarlo primero y reproducir separadamente por ese canal. Si tengo algo de tiempo mas tarde lo codeo, lamentablemente como te explicaba no tengo un dispo con hardware para probarlo bien.